# Jquery .toggle() with first element open

Tags: jquery

So I am using .toggle() to open and close a bunch of divs, but I made the first div open on page load. The problem lies where, if a user click on that div to toggle it closed, it takes two clicks, the first click seems to try to toggle it open again. How should I handle this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content_accrd').css({"height":"0px"});
    $('.content_accrd:eq(0)').css({"height":"100px"});
    $('.paneltop:eq(0)').css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
$('.paneltop').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
    .siblings('.content_accrd').animate({"height":"100px"}, 200)
}, function() {
$(this).css({"background-position":"0px 0px"})
    .siblings('.content_accrd').animate({"height":"0px"}, 200);

})
})
```

markup:

```
 <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                <h2 class="panel_title">Capad Clients</h2>
                <div class="paneltop">
                </div>
              <div class="content_accrd">
              <p>
text
              </p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                <div class="paneltop">
                </div>
              <div class="content_accrd">
              <p>
              text
              </p>
              </div>
          </div>


          <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                <div class="paneltop">
                </div>
              <div class="content_accrd">
              <p>
text
              </p>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MXVHF/)

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content_accrd').css({
        "height": "0px"
    });
    $('.content_accrd:eq(0)').css({
        "height": "100px"
    });
    $('.paneltop:eq(0)').css({
        "background-position": "0px -21px"
    })
    $('.paneltop').click(function() {
        if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').height() != 100) {
            $(this).css({
                "background-position": "0px -21px"
            }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
                "height": "100px"
            }, 200)
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                "background-position": "0px 0px"
            }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
                "height": "0px"
            }, 200);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: With this code, the problem seems to have migrated from the first open div to the other divs, now they need to be clicked on twice to activate

Comment: The edit I just posted checks and toggles based of the siblings height, since the toggle is too broad for multiple classes

Comment: ok sweet, works perfectly and there are some useful techniques in there, thanks a lot!!!